# Create subdomain on the fly Ubuntu bind

Tags: bash, bind, named

what I am trying to do is create a subdomain to a zone that already exist, but i get "update failed: SERVFAIL" error.

What I have so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
record=yyy.mydomain.com
ttl=5
(
 echo "server localhost"
 echo "zone mydomain.com"

 echo "update add ${record} 300 A 217.x.x.x"
 echo "send"
) | /usr/bin/nsupdate
```

Does someone have any idea what am I missing

Comment: that's fine that you have the code above. you have created the entry in the zone file? take a look at this resource: http://www.thecave.info/create-dns-record-for-subdomain/ and when you're done creating the sud omains quickly or on the fly, you can check it with dig.

Comment: when i try to execute it it says : "update failed: SERVFAIL"

  but i dont have this entry in the zone, I want to apear it "on the fly"

Comment: this could be the issue: http://serverfault.com/questions/557224/bind9-servfail-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: here is my zone config:   
zone "mydomain.com" {
 type master;
 file "/etc/bind/zones/mydomain.com";
 allow-update {
                127.0.0.1;
  217.x.x.x;
        };

i am using 14.04, I have "ns      IN      A       217.x.x.x" but I dont have " @ IN A ..... " record . I just dont know what those means :D